# Matching zero or more keywords separated by commas

Tags: bash

I want to match the possibility of zero or more keywords separated by commas.

Am using the following regex

```
if [[ "$var" =~ ^([^,]+(,[^,]+)*)*$ ]]; then
  echo "KY MATCH"
fi
```

I want to match the following

```
var=""
var="keyword"
var="keyword,keyword"
var="keyword,keyword,keyword"
```

Can the regex be simplified or made clearer?

Comment: As with all questions on text processing, please add a representative example of the input, including lines that _should_ match and ones that _shouldn't_, to the question.

Comment: As well as the input and output example requested, please [edit] your question and tell us what kind of regular expression you are using. BRE? ERE? PCRE? Something else? What tools do you want to use to match? What operating system is this on?

Comment: So what do you not want to match? Is `var=someotherleyword`  match? Is `var=blue` a match? Is `var=keyword keyword` (no comma) a match?

Comment: I have put an example, zero or a number of keywords separated by commas.

Comment: Please also show examples that should *not* match. Are you specifically searching for the string `keyword` or repetition of the same string? Is `var="foo,bar"` a match? I think your pattern will match any string that does not contain two commas with no other character in between.

Comment: What is the outcome of this exercise? As of now, since you want to "match zero or more comma-delimited keywords", it sounds as if you want to match string what so ever, including empty strings: `""` is an empty list, `"foo"` contains a word, `"foo,bar"` contains two, so all three match, including combinations and repetitions of each. I don't really see what the code should _do_.

Comment: Veak, what are you actually trying to achieve? I'm seeing many questions from you all very closely related. I can feel there's an objective, but with you only asking a tiny snippet each time I'm not convinced you're going to be getting a good solution. (I know we wouldn't want to write your entire application, but maybe a larger view would be useful.)

Answer (score 0):

Bash uses POSIX extended regular expressions - try `info bash -n 'Conditional Constructs'` and `man 7 regex` (for the first command you need to install `info` and for the second `man-pages`).

If your keywords contain only letters you can  use `[:alpha:]` character class or you can use `[:alnum:]` or `[:word:]`.

Try this script and choose the right class:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

for var in "" "keyword" "keyword,keyword" "keyword,keyword,keyword"; do
    [[ "$var" =~ ^([[:alpha:]]+,?)*$ ]] && echo "$var" MATCHES || echo "$var" DOES NOT MATCH
done

for var in "1" "key word" "key123word,keyword" "keyword, keyword ,keyword"; do
    [[ "$var" =~ ^([[:alpha:]]+,?)*$ ]] && echo "$var" MATCHES || echo "$var" DOES NOT MATCH
done
```

**UPDATE**

As said in the comments, my expression doesn't work for this - `keyword,keyword,`. This expression seems to fit - `^([[:alpha:]]+(,[[:alpha:]]+)*)*$`. I don't see how it could be made simpler.

Comment: `^([[:alpha:]]+,?)*$` would match e.g. `foo,bar,` with the trailing comma, which the original doesn't

Comment: @ilkkachu Oops. But then the regex will be more complicated. Something like that - `^([[:alpha:]]+(,[[:alpha:]]+)*)*$`

Comment: Not much difference, but the part within parentheses is optional, you could swap the last `*` with a `?`.

Answer (score 0):

You can have it much easier if you convert your comma-separated keywords to a regex like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env -S bash - 

#keywords="keyword"
#keywords="aaa,bbb,ccc"
keywords="aaa,bbb,ccc,"
#keywords="ddd,"
#keywords=""

var='aaa'
regex="${keywords%,}"   # trim trailing ','
regex="${regex//,/\|}"  # replace ',' with '|'

printf 'Your var  : %s\n' "$var"
printf 'Your regex: %s\n' "$regex"

if [[ $var =~ ^($regex)$ ]]; then
    printf '%s\n' '-> it matches'
else
    printf '%s\n' '-> it does not match'
fi
```

which results in

```
$ temp/match-comma-separated-keywords.sh
Your var: aaa
Your regex: aaa|bbb|ccc
-> it matches
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the only thing you want to exclude would be empty `,`-separate fields except for the special case where there's no field, so exclude strings where `,` is first or last or there are two consecutive strings, so:

```
case $string in
  (,* | *,,* | *,) echo>&2 not OK;;
  (*) echo OK;;
esac
```

Or

```
case ,${string:-empty}, in
  (*,,*) echo>&2 not OK;;
  (*) echo OK;;
esac
```

Which are standard POSIX sh syntax, or using Korn-style syntax:

`[[ ,${string:-empty}, != *,,* ]]`. No need for `=~`.

A positive regexp for that could be:

```
[[ $string, =~ ^([^,]+,)*$ ]]
```

Though, again, you can do it with wildcard patterns without having to resort to the system's regexp engine and the problems that may come with it (like it choking on non-characters):

```
[[ $string, = *(+([^,]),) ]]
```